# Obtaining the file key of an already-open file channel

Tags: java, nio, filechannel, file-attributes

Is there a way to obtain the [file attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) (specifically, the [file key](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#fileKey())) of an already-open file channel?  This operation would be similar to the [POSIX `fstat` function](https://manpages.debian.org/fstat).

If I know a path of the file, I can call [`Files.readAttributes(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAttributes(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.Class,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)), but this still has a race condition on systems where open files can be deleted or renamed.  I do not see a way to avoid this race condition, so something else would be needed.

Comment: What's wrong with using `Files::readAttributes` on a path with an open channel? Or do you not know its path?

Comment: The race condition. Some systems allow renaming or replacing open files. As a result, there can also be open file channels which no longer have a path to it.

Comment: And how obtaining that key from an open channel (assuming that's possible) will help with that?

Comment: I need the file key (or any other indicator of file identity) for managing advisory file locks, and due to the race, I cannot be sure I got the right file key.

Comment: What about first reading a key, store it somewhere near the channel, then opening the channel, then, at a point where you need to check whether it was replaced, read the key again and compare the two? Normally file channel doesn't read attributes, these are deliberately two separate operations.